# Jquery datepicker showing previous date in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, textbox, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker function on a mvc Html.Textbox, which is bound to my model, the first time I press my search button it gets the correct date in my model, however if I press search again, it should return a different date from the model but it doesn't - it stays cached as the same date that came the first time. I debugged and checked my model contains a new date which it does, but it still shows the old date, I think this is to do with the jquery datepicker setup, how can I stop it from caching this first date?

Here is my MVC code and jquery call:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("MyDate",Model.listOfLoan[i].MyDate.ToShortDateString(), new {@class = "datep"}) %>   



<script language="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datep').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
```

When I debug, the model date has the correct date but it always shows the last date! THanks

Comment: You would get more (accurate) help if you included (relevant parts) of your code, I think.

Comment: If you disable javascript (or comment out the datepicker initialisation line) what do you see in the text box? Do you see the correct date there? (to verify that the problem is because of the date picker and not due to something else)

Comment: Good point vitch, disabled datepicker and it still happens! Any idea why this could be happening even though the model is returnin the right date? All other model variables get updated correctly, just not the date?

Answer (score 0):

David,

Make sure you add $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); into your code i.e:

```
<script language="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $('.datep').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
```

might make it work for you.

jim

btw - you're obviously setting the datepicker against a range of dates with the datep class. what happens if you set the datepicker by individual ID?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I idenitified this as a different problem, not related to jquery but setup of the id! Doh!